# Make a list from shapefiles using GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a number of shapefiles (protected areas for different years) which I would like to dissolve using one attribute. I have not found a line of code to create a list from the shapefiles so iterate through all of them at once.

My files:

```
#files to create a list from 
wdpa95 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa95_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa99 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa99_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa03 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa03_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa07 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa07_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa11 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa11_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa15 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa15_uk_terr.shp')

#dissolve wdpa datasets to create single layer
wdpa95 = gpd.read_file('.../wdpa95_uk_terr.shp')
wdpa95 = wdpa95[['ISO3', 'geometry', 'PA_DEF', 'STATUS_YR']]
wdpa95_dissolve = wdpa95.dissolve(by = 'PA_DEF', aggfunc = 'max')
wdpa95_dissolve.to_file('.../wdpa95_dissolve.shp')
```

I could manually go through the shapefiles one by one but I figured there should a smarter way to create a list and iterate the dissolve process.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that all shapefiles include these attributes: `ISO3`, `geometry`, `PA_DEF`, `STATUS_YR`

```
import os
from glob import glob
import geopandas as gpd

# get list of .shp file names in shp_folder
shp_folder = "folder_path"
shp_files = glob.glob(shp_folder + "/*.shp")

# OR create your own list of file names
# shp_files = ['.../wdpa95_uk_terr.shp', '.../wdpa99_uk_terr.shp', ....]

for file_name in shp_files:
    wdpa = gpd.read_file(file_name)
    wdpa = wdpa[['ISO3', 'geometry', 'PA_DEF', 'STATUS_YR']]
    wdpa_dissolve = wdpa.dissolve(by='PA_DEF', aggfunc='max')

    new_file_name = file_name[:6] + "_dissolve.shp" # wdpa95_dissolve.shp
    # OR 
    # new_file_name = file_name[:-4] + "_dissolve.shp" # wdpa95_uk_terr_dissolve.shp

    new_file_path = os.path.join(shp_folder, new_file_name)
    wdpa_dissolve.to_file(new_file_path)
```